Safari Extension Not Working When Navigate To New Website
I have safari extension that wrap iframes it work fine when open new tab or reload to same website but whenever I try to navigate to new website it breaks no logs print and nothing wrapped on website.
Wrapper.js is the starting point where I have event listner that called the scroll method.
**Wrapper.js:
**
`anyBrowser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender) => {
if(message.wrap){
scroll()
    return
}

if(message.sroll || !message.adlink){
    return
}

}) function scroll(){
try{
let frames = document.body.querySelectorAll('iframe')
//    console.log('Wrapper  wrapper 68')
    
    for(let i = 0; i<frames.length; i++){
//        console.log('Wrapper  wrapper 71')
        
        let r = frames[i].getBoundingClientRect()
        let v = r.top + (r.height/2)
        let vper = v/window.innerHeight
//        console.log('Wrapper  wrapper 76')
        
        frames[i].contentWindow.postMessage({per: vper,id:frames[i].id},'*')
//        console.log('Wrapper  wrapper 79')
        
        
    }
}
catch(error){
    anyBrowser.runtime.sendMessage({
        action: "logError",
        error: "Error From Wrapper 91 line"
        });
}

}`
Then there is one file that contains all the wrapping logic and I have background.js file also that contain event listners.
Manifest.js:
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "default_locale": "en",
    "name": "Tickle",
    "description": "Turbo boos your ads",
    "version": "1.0",
    "web_accessible_resources": [{
        "resources": [ "images/tickle-dark-bg.svg", "images/swipe.svg", "images/arrows.svg","images/download.svg","images/feather.svg","images/featherBlue.svg"],
        "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ]
    }],
    "icons": {
    },
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "pop.html"
    },
    "background": {"service_worker": "scripts/bg.js"},
    "permissions": ["nativeMessaging","webNavigation","activeTab","tabs","<all_urls>"],
    "content_scripts": [
          {"css": [ "css/tickle.css" ],"matches": [ "<all_urls>"], "all_frames":true, "match_about_blank": true },
          {"js": ["scripts/wrapper.js"],"matches": [ "<all_urls>"]},
          {"js": ["content.js"],"matches": [ "<all_urls>"], "all_frames":true, "match_about_blank": true },
          {"js": ["scripts/mole.js"],"matches": [ "<all_urls>"], "all_frames":true, "match_about_blank": true },
          {"js": ["html2canvas.js"],"matches": [ "<all_urls>"], "all_frames":true, "match_about_blank": true }

        ]
}

So the behavior is weird can anyone guide me about this
Clean and clear solution from the developer community

See Is there a JavaScript / jQuery DOM change listener?
